# Ruby reusable map's block

Tags: ruby

I've got the following code that does the job:

```rb
pairs = {
  pair1: {
    first: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}],
    second: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}],
  },
  pair2: {
    first: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}, {d:4}],
    second: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}],
  },
  pair3: {
    first: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}],
    second: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c:3}],
  }
}

pairs.flat_map { |_, t| t[:first] }.reduce Hash.new, :merge
pairs.flat_map { |_, t| t[:second] }.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

I would like to know how it would be possible to make this more elegant by extracting common code into a method. Common code being `map` block. I did read up on Ruby's blocks but I had some difficult time understanding it and could use some help. My initial attempt was:

```rb
def reusable_map_block
  pairs.flat_map(yield).reduce Hash.new, :merge
end

reusable_map_block { |t| t[:first] }
```

```rb
def reusable_map_block(&block)
  pairs.flat_map(block.call).reduce Hash.new, :merge
end

reusable_map_block { |t| t[:first] }
```

```rb
def reusable_map_block(&block)
  pairs.flat_map(block.call).reduce Hash.new, :merge
end

pairs.reusable_map_block { |t| t[:first] }
```

But it's yet not clicking to me. This is just a syntax I'm experimenting with - ultimate goal is giving developer a control which hash to select for further processing and using function as an argument felt natural coming from JS/TS/.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert a block into a [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html) object, you use [the `&` unary prefix ampersand sigil in a parameter list](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument), which will "roll up" the block into a `Proc` object and bind it to that parameter.

In order to convert a `Proc` object into a block, you use [the `&` unary prefix ampersand operator in an argument list](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion), which will "unroll" the `Proc` object into a block:

```rb
def reusable_map_block(pairs, &block)
  pairs.flat_map(&block).reduce Hash.new, :merge
end

reusable_map_block(pairs) { |_, t| t[:first] }
```

You can add this as an extension method to the [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) class if you want:

```rb
class Hash
  def reusable_map_block(&block)
    flat_map(&block).reduce Hash.new, :merge
  end
end

pairs.reusable_map_block { |_, t| t[:first] }
```

However, when monkey-patching, it is generally preferred to use a clearly named module, so that the monkey-patch shows up in the inheritance chain, and the name of the module gives you an indication for the name of the file you should look into:

```rb
module ReusableMapBlockExtension
  def reusable_map_block(&block)
    flat_map(&block).reduce Hash.new, :merge
  end
end

class Hash
  include ReusableMapBlockExtension
end

pairs.reusable_map_block { |_, t| t[:first] }
```

Even better yet, if you know that your code will only be run on Ruby implementations that support [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), you could use that:

```rb
module ReusableMapBlockExtension
  def reusable_map_block(&block)
    flat_map(&block).reduce Hash.new, :merge
  end
end

module HashWithReusableMapBlock
  refine Hash do
    include ReusableMapBlockExtension
  end
end

pairs.reusable_map_block { |_, t| t[:first] }
# NoMethodError (undefined method `reusable_map_block' for #<Hash:0x00007f8442831e68>)

using HashWithReusableMapBlock

pairs.reusable_map_block { |_, t| t[:first] }
#=> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be accessible on your `pairs` directly you need to add that method to the class. I've made a slight alteration since you'll need to use `self` instead of `pairs` which no longer exists:

```
class Hash
  def reusable_map_block(&block)
    values.flat_map(&block).reduce(Hash.new, :merge)
  end
end
```

If you're okay with that then you can get the result you want:

```
pairs.reusable_map_block { |t| t[:first] }
```

You may want to give this a more meaningful name like `reduce_values` or something of the sort.

Comment: `self` isn't needed and you can pass the block directly: `flat_map(&block)`

Comment: @Stefan Good point. In an earlier iteration I hadn't used `values` yet, so that block had to split out the second part of the pair.